# Is it possible that $L=0$ is a partial limit of $a_n$?

Tags: calculus

Given: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_na_{n+1})=1$$

Is it possible to say that $L=0$ is a partial limit of $a_n$?
I don't see how we can show such a thing because the limit of $a_{n+1}$ will always be the limit of $a_n$

Comment: What about $$a_n = \exp((-1)^n \log(n+1)) = (n+1)^{(-1)^n}?$$

Comment: The question is unclear.  If you mean, "Must it be true that $0$ is a limit of a subsequence?", then the answer "no" follows from looking at $(1,1,1,\ldots)$.  If you mean, "Is is possible for $0$ to be a limit of a subsequence?", then the answer "yes" follows from the answers of Idris and me.dorgan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the sequence

$$2,\frac{1}{2}, 3, \frac{1}{3}, \dots, n, \frac{1}{n}, n+1, \frac{1}{n+1}, \dots $$

Answer (score 1):

take $a_{2n}=1/2n$ and $a_{2n+1}=2n+1$

Comment: But doesn't it mean that $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ hence $a_{2n}=\frac{1}{2n}$ hence $a_{2n+1}$ should be $a_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2n+1}$?

Comment: $a_n=1/n$ only for $n=2k$ and $a_n=n$ only for $n=2k+1$. My sequence is almost the same as that given by me.dorgan

Comment: Oh I see thanks